# Is it good practice to override fetch() and save() directly from the Model?

Tags: backbone.js

I don't want to override `Backbone.sync()` as some of my models will actually use the standard `sync()`.

Is it good practice to override `fetch()` and `save()` directly from the Model?

Comment: If don't want overwrite `Backbone.sync()` you always can override `MyModel.sync()`. If you go to override `MyModel.fetch()` and `MyModel.save()` maybe you have to override also `MyModel.destroy()`. Anyhow I think everything depends on your reason to no using the standard _sync_ methods?

Comment: @fguillen Some of my models will use localStorage while others will use server-side saving...

Comment: Then I'd do it overriding the `MyModel.sync()`, should there be out there implementations of LocalStorage for Backbone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to override `sync` globally. You can do it per Model/Collection ie,

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: customSync,
    ...
});
```

This avoids overriding Backbone.sync globally.

Now if you do not need to implement a full sync, for instance it you only need to override `fetch`, you can of course do so on a per model basis too.

Presumably you have seen Backbone.sync being overriden by the localStorage version. This is indeed not necessary (I would think it is bad practice). It is sufficient to just define the custom `sync` function and let models/collections use it.